# Clone Linux OS Btrfs disk and boot with cloned disk 2024?

Tags: boot, system-installation, disk, btrfs, clone

Disk D is a typical Linux installation. D has EFI (boot) and Btrfs (the rest) partitions. If I have a disk E whose size is > D, how can I clone D on E, and boot with E? Is that possible without too much effort?

Comment: D and E are DOS/Windows disk names, and mean nothing in Unix-like environments.

Comment: They are just arbitrary names I used not to repeat the description again; they have nothing to do with Windows drive names. I'm not even using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the following steps:

1. Literally 1:1 clone the disk using `dd`.
2. Remove the old disk.
3. Boot the new disk.
4. Use a partitioning tool to grow the main partition and/or to add extra partitions, to make use of the larger disk.

The answer hasn't really changed since 2023, or 2022, or 2021, or 2020. For that matter, I don't think it has changed any since 2000.

There are ways to improve it, e.g. by replacing the raw `dd` with:

1. using `sfdisk --dump` to clone the partition table,
2. then using `partclone.btrfs` or `ntfsclone` to transfer large partitions more efficiently by avoiding the unnecessary copy of "unused" space,
3. then, if the disk is used for BIOS/CSM boot, using `head -c 440` to transfer the boot sector code to the new disk's MBR (not needed for EFI boot).

Comment: Most systems today are using EFI. It would be necessary to set up boot loader in EFI variables for this to work, unless something like fallback shim is used.

Comment: @Vilinkameni: The EFI variables reference disks by their GPT "partition GUID", which is cloned along with the rest of the GPT.

Comment: But they would need to be recreated if transferred to another machine.